# Need to change title color donut highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my function which renders donut high chart in my html. I am able to put the dynamic color to the legend marker/icon. But now I need to put the dynamic color to the legend title as well. I could figure out this.

How can I do that? Please help!!!

```
    const chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
      {
        chart: {
          color: '#000',
          backgroundColor: '#336196',
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
          text: "What's using data",
          style: {
            color: '#000'
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            shadow: false,
            borderColor: null
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' %'
          }
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'right',
          layout: 'vertical',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          symbolRadius: 0,
          symbolPadding: 10,
          itemMarginTop: 15,
          itemStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: data,
            size: '120%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            marker: {
              symbol: 'square',
              radius: 12
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      function(chart) {
        var textX = chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth * 0.5
        var textY = chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight * 0.52

        var span =
          '<div id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">'
        span +=
          '<div style="color:#fff;font-size: 20px;width:50pxmargin-top:36px;margin-left:18px;"></div><br>'
        span += '</div>'

        $('#addText').append(span)
        span = $('#pieChartInfoText')
        span.css('left', textX + span.width() * -0.5)
        span.css('top', textY + span.height() * -0.5)
      }
    )
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: A simple google search could've done that for you: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HighChart Title text implemented HTML Style is not applying in exporting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062908/highchart-title-text-implemented-html-style-is-not-applying-in-exporting-files)

Comment: @Megajin Neither `title.style` or the duplicate target you have linked are appropriate here.They are completely unrelated as far as I can see.

Comment: @Megajin that's a line chart I am asking about donut_chart. Makes difference.

Comment: @ewolden Any solution please?

Comment: Guys, I marked it as a duplicate because it leads to the same answer (@ewolden). @DarkKnight have you tried to put `style: {color: 'red'}` in your legend block? Because that works. If you want to change something in the series simply set `color: 'red'`. However that all can be read through the docs: [ItemStyle](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle) and here [series color](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#4). If that doesn't appeal you, then just change dynamically the css class. It is really simple.

Comment: @Megajin It will fill same color to all the legends. I need dynamic. Have a look at the answer and given fiddle in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the legend color title, simply set:

```
    legend: {
        title: {
            text: 'legend title',
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
```

But, if you want to change individual legend item text, you need to use:

```
function(chart) {
    var legendItems = $(".highcharts-legend-item");
    $(legendItems[0].children[0]).css('fill', 'red');
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/avhtLm3w/

Comment: Setting color is not the issue, he wants to set color dynamically. I.e. for the legend text to match the color of each slice of the pie. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466285/change-legend-color-high-charts-based-on-data

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ewolden. However, I think that my answer is correct, it is easy to achieve the required result, using the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3z781xu9/

Comment: @ewolden and ppotaczek the answer works but the color disappears on hower. Please give me suggestions

Comment: Hi Dark Knight, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ngsaxd1c/ and please let me know if this meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs.](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.style)

```
title:{
  text: 'Something',
  style: {"color": "#003C71", "fontSize": "18px"}
}
```

this will do the trick